# Celery not returning any results after success?

Tags: django, django-views, scrapy, celery

Here I am crawling some websites with different keywords. Before It was only scraping and it worked but I implemented celery for this. After using celery I am not being able to get the scraping result but no error is showing. I am using `rabbitmq` as the message broker here.

tasks.py

```
@shared_task()
def schedule_task(pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=pk)
    keywords = ''
    # for keys in ast.literal_eval(obj.keywords.all()): #keywords change to csv
    for keys in task.keywords.all():
        if keywords:
            keywords += ', ' + keys.title
        else:
            keywords += keys.title

    task_ids = []  # one Task/Project contains one or multiple scrapy task

    settings = {
        'spider_count': len(task.targets.all()),
        'keywords': keywords,
        'unique_id': str(uuid4()),  # unique ID for each record for DB
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
    }

    # res = ast.literal_eval(ini_list)

    for site_url in task.targets.all():
        domain = urlparse(site_url.address).netloc  # parse the url and extract the domain
        spider_name = domain.replace('.com', '')
        task = scrapyd.schedule('default', spider_name, settings=settings, url=site_url.address, domain=domain,
                                keywords=keywords)
```

views

```
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = CreateTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            unique_id = str(uuid4())  # create a unique ID.
            obj = form.save(commit=False)

            obj.created_by = request.user
            obj.unique_id = unique_id
            obj.status = 0
            obj.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            print(obj.pk)
            schedule_task.delay(pk=obj.pk)
            return redirect('crawler:task-list')
```

views before using celery ( which returns the **scraped** results worked fine) I just split the scraping part into tasks.py and call it from view with `.delay` but didn't returned the result(before it returned).

```
form = CreateTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            
            unique_id = str(uuid4()) # create a unique ID. 
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            
            obj.created_by = request.user
            obj.unique_id = unique_id
            obj.status = 0
            obj.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            keywords = ''
            # for keys in ast.literal_eval(obj.keywords.all()): #keywords change to csv
            for keys in obj.keywords.all():
                if keywords:
                    keywords += ', ' + keys.title
                else:
                    keywords += keys.title
            
            task_ids = [] #one Task/Project contains one or multiple scrapy task

            settings = {
                'spider_count' : len(obj.targets.all()),
                'keywords' : keywords,
                'unique_id': unique_id, # unique ID for each record for DB
                'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
            }

            # res = ast.literal_eval(ini_list) 

            for site_url in obj.targets.all():
                domain = urlparse(site_url.address).netloc # parse the url and extract the domain
                spider_name = domain.replace('.com', '')
                task = scrapyd.schedule('default', spider_name, settings=settings, url=site_url.address, domain=domain, keywords=keywords)

            return redirect('crawler:task-list')
```

celery console

```
[2020-06-10 20:42:55,885: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-ENPLHOS ready.
[2020-06-10 20:42:55,900: INFO/MainProcess] pidbox: Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//.
[2020-06-10 20:43:13,730: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: crawler.tasks.schedule_task[10e7bf06-5e4e-413c-85a3-79d61b9835cf]
[2020-06-10 20:43:17,077: INFO/MainProcess] Task crawler.tasks.schedule_task[10e7bf06-5e4e-413c-85a3-79d61b9835cf] succeeded in 3.3590000000040163s: None
```

`http://localhost:6800/jobs` here I can see the spiders are running but the results are not appearing in my view.

Comment: Do you try [Keeping Results](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results) section from celery’s docs?

Comment: I'm believing your command to call celery could be missing something. According to this [post](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3759#issuecomment-311763355), you may need to add `-P solo` to your command like: `celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency 1 -P solo`

Answer (score 1):

> views before using celery ( which returns the **scraped** results worked fine)

that is because your code runs **synchronous**....one after the other.

Celery on the other hand runs **asynchronous** and alway you will get a `None` as the returned value from it.

If you chain 2 or more Celery tasks (of which all of them run async) then you can make use of their returned value, but not chaining a `synchronous view` with an `async celery task`.

Celery tasks are meant to be dispatched and run in background...while your view is suppose to return something else...(without waiting for your spiders to finish)

To be able to make use of the `Celery results`:

**Collected data needs to be stored somewhere (a file like `csv`, `json`, etc, .. OR inside a `database`)  and handle the `Django View` in 2 steps:**

- **first you trigger the Celery task**
- **second collect the stored results and display them**

Comment: then what might be the solution to this problem? Any suggestions how can I scrap using celery ?

Comment: The Celery results needs to be stored somewhere (a file like csv, json, etc, .. OR inside a database)  and handle the Django View in 2 steps: first you trigger the Celery task, second collect the stored results and display them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll try to do this